# Data scraping in Shopee product names are not showing their proper name respectively

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So i am trying to **scrape** Data in Shopeee using Pycharm/Python and Selenium. here is the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://shopee.ph/search?keyword=nacific&noCorrection=true&page=0&withDiscount=true")
time.sleep(2)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
time.sleep(3)

Categories = []
Categories.append(["NAME"])
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='row shopee-search-item-result__items']/div")

for product in products:
    name_p = product.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='yQmmFK _1POlWt _36CEnF']")

    rowData = [name_p]
    Categories.append(rowData)

with open('Shopee.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    Import = csv.writer(file,lineterminator='\n')
    Import.writerows(Categories)
```

so after i ran it...i "succcessfully" run it but the problem is this:
[image: Screenshot A]

rather than showing the name of product it show selenium.webdriver and so on
i tried to change to other code by not using xpath and do the regular way(find_element_by_class_name etc) but it still cause error. i wonder why it is not working? can someone help me?

Website im trying to **scrape**: Shopee.ph
Software: Pycharm and Selenium

Comment: Instead of writing `rowData = [name_p]` try `rowData = [name_p.text]` -- `name_p` is a webelement not a string.

Comment: Hi C.Peck i tried to do it and yes it works finally, the problem is however is that, the names of the products...or rather product shows only 1 product: "NACIFIC Nutrition Herb Origin Serum 50ml 1+1" from column1 and so on. only 1 product name rather than the all products of the Shopee page. i wonder why? suppose to be the intention is to take all products of the website displayed. but it only took the 1st product then repeat it entirely to each column cell of the excel...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.text` to get the text from Selenium WebElements.

Example

```
product.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='yQmmFK _1POlWt _36CEnF']").text
```

There're many ways to locate web elements.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("passwd-id")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("passwd")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='passwd-id']")
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#passwd-id")
```

You can find the document here.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

I've also fixed some of your code. Here

```
products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('yQmmFK')

for product in products:
    name_p = product.text
    rowData = [name_p]
    Categories.append(rowData)
driver.close()
```